# hc-append unbound identifier in module in

Tags: racket

Hello I am following [the quick introduction to racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/quick/). In chapter 5 they propose that this code (which worked fine):

```
(define (four p)
  (define two-p (hc-append p p))
  (vc-append two-p two-p))
```

would tipically be written by using let, so I wrote my code:

```
#lang slideshow

(define (square n)
  (filled-rectangle n n))
(define (four p)
  (let ([two-p (hc-apppend p p)])
  (vc-append two-p two-p)))
```

but it doesn't work. 
The error message is:

```
expand: unbound identifier in module in: hc-apppend
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just checking: Did you remember

```
#lang slideshow
```

as the first line?

Also, count the number of **p** characters! It is hc-append.  The error mentions *hc-apppend*: it should be *hc-append*.

Comment: yes, of course, otherwise it would not work the first block of code

Comment: In that case it is indeed strange. Your example works for me.

Comment: Just tried it again in a newer DrRacket and now I see the problem too.

Comment: @ohjoata Ahh! Count the number of ps! It is hc-append.

Comment: ups, I can not believe I loose so much time because of a p :P